# How to switch from an existing website to Wordpress website?

Tags: customization

I have a non-profit website that needs a LOT of work. I would like to start fresh with WordPress. How would I do that--I already have our name ...kenyareal.org

Comment: This is a very broad topic. It depends what you needs are, what you currently have going on your website, what else you want on your website, etc. I would suggest [finding a theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/) that fits your needs and [install it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to agree with JDM2112. Start of with installing WP. Then write down everything your site needs to do and find the right plugins and themes to accomplish these goals.

Here's some helpfull info aswell to get you to grips with WordPress installs and its backend install.[Beginners guide to using WordPress](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/courses/a-beginners-guide-to-using-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

Using the step-by-step installation directions on the WordPress Codex is a good way to get up and running with a WP site.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress

From there, and depending on your HTML and PHP experience, you might either begin developing your own custom theme, or browse the many thousands of pre-built themes available.